# tengo un problema con mi código y es que cuando ejecuto se cierra solo, el codigo trata del juego de la serpiente en c++ con allegro

Tags: c++, allegro

estoy utilizando la librería **Allegro**

```
#include <allegro.h>
#define LARGO 1000
#define ANCHO 720
#define LIMITE_NODOS 200
BITMAP *buffer;
BITMAP *cabeza1;
BITMAP *cabeza2;
BITMAP *cabeza3;
BITMAP *cabeza4;
BITMAP *nodo_cuerpo;
BITMAP *comida;
BITMAP *corazon;

int LIMITE_X=LARGO/40;
int LIMITE_Y=ANCHO/40;
int TAM = 3;

struct Nodo{
    int x,y;
};

Nodo cuerpo[LIMITE_NODOS];

void setup(){
    allegro_init();
    install_keyboard();
    set_color_depth(32);
    set_gfx_mode(GFX_AUTODETECT_WINDOWED,LARGO,ANCHO,0,0);
    buffer = create_bitmap(LARGO,ANCHO);

    cabeza1 = create_bitmap(40,40);
    cabeza2 = create_bitmap(40,40);
    cabeza3 = create_bitmap(40,40);
    cabeza4 = create_bitmap(40,40);
    nodo_cuerpo = create_bitmap(40,40);
    comida = create_bitmap(40,40);
    corazon = create_bitmap(40,40);
    cabeza1 = load_bitmap("imagenes/cara1.bmp",NULL);
    cabeza2 = load_bitmap("imagenes/cara2.bmp",NULL);
    cabeza3 = load_bitmap("imagenes/cara3.bmp",NULL);
    cabeza4 = load_bitmap("imagenes/cara4.bmp",NULL);
    nodo_cuerpo = load_bitmap("imagenes/cuerpo.bmp",NULL);
    comida = load_bitmap("imagenes/manzana.bmp",NULL);
    corazon = load_bitmap("imagenes/Corazon.bmp",NULL);
}
```

Al principio pensé que se trataba de la ubicación de las imágenes, pero la ubicación es correcta.

[image: ubicación del programa y las carpetas]

esta parte es para dibujar los bordes

```
void dibujar_bordes(){
    rectfill(buffer,0,40,LARGO,80,0X0000FF);
    rectfill(buffer,0,ANCHO-40,LARGO,ANCHO,0X0000FF);
    rectfill(buffer,0,40,40,ANCHO,0X0000FF);
    rectfill(buffer,LARGO-40,40,LARGO,ANCHO,0X0000FF);
}
```

esta parte para actualizar pantalla

```
void actualizar_pantalla(){
    blit(buffer,screen,0,0,0,0,LARGO,ANCHO);
}
```

aquí se genera la serpiente y en esta parte no hay problema

```
void generar_serpiente(){
    cuerpo[0].x=10;
    cuerpo[0].y=9;
    for(int i=1;i<=TAM;i++){
        cuerpo[i].x=cuerpo[0].x-i;
        cuerpo[i].y=cuerpo[0].y;
    }
}
```

en esta parte viene el problema, cuando elimino esta función, el programa se ejecuta perfectamente.

```
void dibujar_serpiente(){
    for(int i=0;i<TAM;i++) {
         draw_sprite(buffer,nodo_cuerpo,cuerpo[i].x*40,cuerpo[i].y*40);
    }
}

int main(){
     setup();
     dibujar_bordes();
     generar_serpiente();
     dibujar_serpiente();
     actualizar_pantalla();
     readkey();    
     return 0;
```

creo que el problema esta en la función "dibujar serpiente()" ya que cuando la elimino del int main, funciona correctamente y al llamarla de nuevo el programa se cierra solo después de unos segundos.

Comment: Hola Eracles, bienvenido, podrías editar tu pregunta y agregar los mensajes de error que recibes?.

Comment: no recibo ningún error

Comment: He estado buceando un poco, y me encontré con que llaman a la función que tu nombras **draw_sprite** como **raw_sprite**, podrá ser ese el problema?.

Comment: ya verifique y esta como draw_sprite

Comment: gracias, ya me ayudaron a solucionarlo y era por las imágenes no me fije que la imagen en realidad era de 100x100 en lugar de 40x40, solo hizo falta recórtalas y ya

Comment: Buenísimo. grande maestro!!.